# Sql Dependency - Notification received before processing current request

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldependency, query-notifications

I am currently using sql dependency notification to detect changes in a table and process them. I am having a problem where the notification gets called while its still in the middle of completing the first request which causes duplicate processing

```
private void ProcessData()
    {
        try
        {

                m_Guids = new List<Guid>();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_XXX_SELECT", m_sqlConn))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
                    SqlDependency.Start(m_ConnectionString, m_QueueName);

                    if (m_sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        m_sqlConn.Open();
                    }

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                m_Guids.Add(reader.GetGuid(0));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(m_Guids.Count.ToString());
                    ProcessGuids();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            //SendFailureEmail
        }
    }

private void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange;
    ProcessData();
}    

public void OnStart()
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(m_ConnectionString, m_QueueName);
    SqlDependency.Start(m_ConnectionString, m_QueueName);
    m_sqlConn = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString);
}
```

ProcessData method gets called again while its still in the middle of processing (processGuids) Should I subscribe to the event after processing all the data?
If I don't subscribe until processing is complete, what happens to the data that was changed during the process, which I believe doesn't get notified until next change happens?. What is the correct way of doing this or am I doing something wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SqlDependency.OnChange is called not only on data change.

In the OnDependencyChange you must check `e.Type`/`e.Source`/`e.Info`.

F.e., combination of `{Type = Subscribe, Source = Statement, Info = Invalid}` means "**Statement not ready for notification, no notification started**".
See [Creating a Query for Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx) for SQL statement requirements for notification. You must follow these requirements in SELECT statements in your SP.

Additional requirements for stored procedures are not well documented. Known restrictions for SP:

- Use of SET NOCOUNT (ON and OFF) is prohibited.
- Use of RETURN is prohibited.